# How can I prove I arrived in the USA in 2016 from Fiji?

Tags: usa

I worked as a volunteer in Fiji Islands from 2012 to 2016. I flew back to Los Angeles on June 15, 2016 from Nadi, Fiji Islands with Fiji Airways. I did not go back to Fiji. I did not keep my boarding pass nor was my passport stamped on arrival by DHS in Los Angeles.

I applied for my Medicare coverage and the late enrollment penalty can be waived if I produce a government-issued document that confirms I returned on June 15th, 2016. I will appreciate if you suggest where I can get some document confirming that I arrived back in the USA on June 15, 2016.

Comment: If you are not a US citizen or permanent resident, you can look up your travel records at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

Answer (score 8):

You can [submit a Freedom of Information Act request](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia) with Customs and Border Protection for your arrival/departure records. That's likely to show your entry in 2016, though it could take quite some time to receive a response.

You might also ask whether they'll accept secondary forms of evidence. Perhaps you could supply a copy of your plane tickets and credit card/bank statements that show you making charges in Fiji before that date and in the United States after that date.

Answer (score 3):

The airline will still have a record of your flight.
You can ask them to get a print out, or even get it online.

Comment: To expand on that, the 6 letter boarding code is discarded shortly after your flight, but the ticket number is kept for quite a while longer (years?). The ticket number might show up on your receipt. This is what you can use to retrieve a travel doc from the airline.